# PHP Mysqli always returns 0 rows

Tags: php, mysqli

**Issue details**

I always get `rows count = 0`.

[image]

**Below is the code that fetches info from database.**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "homework");

$UserName = "test";
if($result = $con->prepare("SELECT * from tbluser where User_Name=?")) {
    $result->bind_param("s", $UserName);
    $result->execute();
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    echo $row_cnt; //Always returns 0 row
    $result->close();
}
$con->close();
```

Below is the print of `$result` after executing this line. `$result->execute();`

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

mysqli_stmt Object
(
    [affected_rows] => -1
    [insert_id] => 0
    [num_rows] => 0
    [param_count] => 1
    [field_count] => 4
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [id] => 1
)
```

Comment: Did you check the intermediate results, for instance the result of `$result->execute();`, which will return false, or call `$result->get_result()` which will give you a resultset or false, or check `$result->error` (and related properties) for error information.

Comment: @GolezTrol : I added the result of `$result` variable

Comment: Actually, looking [at the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php), (always a good idea), you will read that num_rows is only populated after you fetch the result set. So you actually have to call store_result first. *"Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle."*

Comment: Alternatively, it seems you can call [result_metadata](`http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php`), or even better, turn the query into a `count` query, if you only want to get the number of rows that match.

Comment: You have a where statement searching for User_Name =? And unless this is a command I do not recognise it will return zero results if nothing matches it in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the manual

> If you do not use mysqli_stmt_store_result( ), and immediatley call this function after executing a prepared statement, this function will usually return 0 as it has no way to know how many rows are in the result set as the result set is not saved in memory yet.

```
// First add this so you are sure you will get shown any errors

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "homework");

$UserName = "test";
if($result = $con->prepare("SELECT * from tbluser where User_Name=?")) {
    $result->bind_param("s", $UserName);
    $status = $result->execute();

    // new line of code
    $result->store_result();

    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    echo $row_cnt; //Always returns 0 row
    $result->close();
}
$con->close();
```

Comment: I was missing this line of code. `$result->store_result();` 

Question: Is `store_result` working in synchronous way?  As per the docs here : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php **If you use mysqli_stmt_store_result(), mysqli_stmt_num_rows() may be called immediately.**

Comment: Try adding the error display code, in case something else is a probem here

Comment: Yes. Pretty much everything in PHP is synchronous.